# Query couchdb to retrieve specific views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, couchdb

I am using Ruby on Rails with Couchdb as my database. In it I have a `User` model which I want query. My goal is to look at every user in `users` table and retrieve those which do not have a last name. I have read around online but am unable to determine how to do this from my rails console.

I can do `User.first.last_name`

, but how do I improve on this query to accomplish my above stated goal?

Comment: Do you want to do this repeatedly, or is this just a one off? Are you wanting to create a view of users with no last name? Do you a have a view keyed on last name?

Answer (score 1):

Well you can simply do this:

```
# option 1
User.where(:lastname => nil).each do |usr|
  # do something 
end

# option 2
users_without_last_name = User.where(:last_name => nil)
if user_without_last_name.any?
   #do something 
end
```